# How to show 5 posts from specific category on related page?

Tags: categories, pages, widgets

I'm not familiar enough with wordpress to ask the question directly, so please bare with me as I explain what I'm looking for.

I have four primary sections of my business (A, B, C & D, for example).

- each section has it's own page
- each section also has a category with the same name
- various pages and posts are categorized under each section

I want an area in the sidebar (probably a widget) to show N (probably ~5) summaries of items categorized as A on page A.  And the same on pages B, C & D.

Remembering that I am a Drupal developer who does not know the Wordpress landscape very well, how would I go about this?  Is there a ready-built widget or am I looking at something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin
http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-sidebar/screenshots/

and use widget logic to display particular category posts
http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/screenshots/

Please add is_page('A') in widget logic section
Then select posts form category A in posts in sidebar

Comment: This does work but isn't particularly scaleable.

Comment: @mrwweb: agreed.  I did end up using this but I don't love it for this reason.  Required adding a widget to the sidebar for each category.  I found the http://wordpress.org/plugins/related-posts plugin which uses it's own logic (it does not use categories in the way I had intended), but does a very nice job.  If the client is careless about categorizing things, we may just use this instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably ditch categories and use the Parent field which is for establishing a hierarchical relationship between pages. You'd then use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) to make a custom loop outputting your summaries.

You'd end up with something like this:

```
<?php $related_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
));
if( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : while( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : $related_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="hentry">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="entry-summary"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Categories could work and you'd just need to use a different query, but the Parent field is made for this exact purpose. It *lives for this.* I could also imagine a solution using menus to manage the relationship, but I like Parent still.

If you want this to be a widget, it wouldn't take much to [wrap this up as a widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

Comment: I like this approach more, but due to time constraints didn't follow up on it.  I was thinking of using your logic either with the `php-code-widget` or with the `section-widget` and your code in a custom shortcode (nice article here: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/)